# Что не так с системой?

Tags: ubuntu, apache

Есть вот такой вызов:...

```
jQuery("#brenger-plugin-submit-form").click(function(){
    var pick = jQuery("input[name=pickup-address-city]").val();
    var dest = jQuery("input[name=delivery-location]").val();
    if(pick == ""){
        alert("Please enter pickup address in WP-Admin->Brenger API Settings");
    }

    if(dest == ""){
        jQuery("input[name=delivery-location]").css("border","1px solid red");
    }
    if(pick != "" && dest != ""){
        window.open('https://www.brenger.nl/nl?delivery_address[city]='+dest+'&pickup_address[city]='+pick);
    }
});
```

...который будучи запущенным с localhost вызывает на сайте www.brenger.nl ошибку
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 1171456 bytes) in /data/web/brenger/brenger.production-env.com/htdocs2/docroot/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Database/Statement.php on line 59
если сформированный запрос просто скопировать в строку браузера - всё работает. На хостинге также всё работает великолепно.
Вопрос: что у меня не так с localhost?

apache2 2.4
ubuntu 17.04

```
Mutex file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} default
PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}
Timeout 300
KeepAlive On
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
KeepAliveTimeout 5
User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}
HostnameLookups Off
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
LogLevel warn
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.conf
Include ports.conf
<Directory /home/user/wpwork>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
AccessFileName .htaccess
<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>
LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent
IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf
IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf
<VirtualHost *:8011>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /home/user/wpwork
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Замените `window.open` на `console.log` и опубликуйте получившуюся строку

Comment: Мой код как есть работает на хостинге Ubuntu 16.04/Apache2. Я хочу решить проблему с системой.

Comment: Ну как хотите. Мое дело предложить направление в поиске решения.

Comment: Спасибо за участие, Результирующая строка вида https://www.brenger.nl/nl?delivery_address[city]=Minderhout&pickup_address[city]=Amsterdam прекрасно работает если скопировать в браузер.

Comment: А теперь замените весь ваш обработчик `click` одной строкой `window.open('https://www.brenger.nl/nl?delivery_address[city]=Minderhout&pickup_address[city]=Amsterdam');`

Comment: Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 585728 bytes) in /data/web/brenger/brenger.production-env.com/htdocs2/docroot/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Database/Statement.php on line 59 примерно то же.

Comment: Посмотрите каким-нибудь просмотрщиком какой именно пакет уходит на сервер

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76589/discussion-between-vlad-visitor-and-anton-shchyrov).

Comment: Думаю, что быстрее всего подобные проблемы исправляются отправкой баг-репорта владельцам сайта..

Answer (score 0):

Сайту brenger.nl не нравится localhost. Соорудил что-то подобное...`

```
<VirtualHost my.homelinux.com:80>
        ServerName my.homelinux.com
        DocumentRoot /home/user/wpwork/
        ErrorLog "/var/log/apache2/error.my.homelinux.com.log"
        CustomLog "/var/log/apache2/access.my.homelinux.com.log" common
        <Directory /home/user/wpwork>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
            Require all granted
        </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>
```

...и стало работать

Answer (score 0):

Причину я вам не назову. Но должен помочь такой маневр:

В PHP.ini измените значение `memory_limit = 128M;` (как пример) в большую сторону.

Если этот файл изменить невозможно, попробуйте в.htaccess добавить: `php_value memory_limit 128M`  (как пример)

Comment: Я же не имею отношения к сайту brenger.nl , и думаю, что его админ вряд ли будет это ради меня делать)

Comment: Но всё равно спасибо за участие